# SQLite python how to add multiple filters in SELECT

Tags: python, sqlite, select, filter

How can I add more than one filter in a sql SELECT?
I would need three different filter/parameters for a sql SELECT.
Currently I have one and it looks like that:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect(SerienPlaner)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = """SELECT %s
       FROM TVShowData
       WHERE julianday(_Starttime) + (_RunningTime / 24.0 / 60.0) > julianday('now', 'localtime')
       %s
       ORDER BY _Starttime
       LIMIT 15"""
if category == __LS__(30116):
    filter = ""
    parameters = ()
else:
    filter = " AND WatchType = ?"
    parameters = (category,)

query = query % (','.join(properties), filter)
cur.execute(query, parameters)
```

I would like to add

```
if __series_in_db__:
    filter = " AND inDB = ?"
    parameters = (TRUE,)
else:
    filter = ""
    parameters = ()
```

and

```
if __firstaired__:
    filter = " AND neueEpisode = ?"
    parameters = %NEU%
else:
    filter = ""
    parameters = ()
```

`__series_in_db__` and `__firstaired__` are GUI-settings within the script...
for `__firstaired__` I would like fatchall where neueEpisode = NEU or FREE-TV NEU...

Comment: From a code maintenance perspective, reconsider your approach here. Instead of conditionally creating the SQL statement simply create whole SQL strings based on if/then/else conditions.

Comment: @Parfait Three optional filters would result in eight cases. And all the parameters *are* values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just append the SQL/parameters to the previous one:

```
filter = ""
parameters = []
if ...:
    filter += " AND xxx = ?"
    parameters += [x]
if ...:
    filter += " AND yyy = ?"
    parameters += [y]
```